# Windows Phone 7 Keyboard "Done" key?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there an yway to change the default <kbd>enter</kbd> key on the Windows Phone 7 keyboard to <kbd>Done</kbd> or some other key like <kbd>Send</kbd> or whatever like the iPhone has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `InputScope` on the textbox to control what is displayed in the SIP. Many of these include variations on the 'enter' key.

You can see images of all the different scopes (yes, many of them are the same) at http://www.wpfied.com/2011/05/input-scopes-in-windows-phone-7/